# SQL Server WHERE Clause using Temporary Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, calculated-columns

I have the following query, which uses a CASE statement.
Is there anyway to add into the where clause WHERE IsBusinessDayFinal = 0? without using a temporary table?

thanks so much!

```
SELECT 
        ac.DateTimeValue,
        CASE 
            WHEN pc.IsBusinessDay IS NOT NULL THEN pc.IsBusinessDay
            ELSE ac.IsBusinessDay
        END AS IsBusinessDayFinal,
        ac.FullYear,
        ac.MonthValue,
        ac.DayOfMonth,
        ac.DayOfWeek,
        ac.Week 
    FROM 
        [dbo].[AdminCalendar] ac LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].ProjectCalendar pc ON ac.DateTimeValue = pc.DateTimeValue AND pc.ProjectId = @projectId
    WHERE ac.DateTimeValue >= @startDate AND ac.DateTimeValue <= @finishDate;
```

Comment: could you to use a subselect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
WHERE (pc.IsBusinessDay IS NULL AND ac.IsBusinessDay = 0)
OR pc.IsBusinessDay = 0
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realize that the solution was actually really simple. I guess I didn't think hard enough. =p

Comment: +1. Even though logic is identical, I prefer your IS NULL version!

Answer (score 2):

```
WHERE ac.DateTimeValue >= @startDate AND ac.DateTimeValue <= @finishDate
      AND ((pc.IsBusinessDay IS NOT NULL AND pc.IsBusinessDay = 0) OR ac.IsBusinessDay = 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [COALESCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258244%28SQL.80%29.aspx) instead of CASE because you're checking for null:

```
SELECT ac.DateTimeValue,
       COALESCE(pc.IsBusinessDay, ac.IsBusinessDay) AS IsBusinessDayFinal,
       ac.FullYear,
       ac.MonthValue,
       ac.DayOfMonth,
       ac.DayOfWeek,
       ac.Week 
  FROM [dbo].[AdminCalendar] ac 
LEFT JOIN [dbo].ProjectCalendar pc ON ac.DateTimeValue = pc.DateTimeValue 
                                  AND pc.ProjectId = @projectId
WHERE ac.DateTimeValue >= @startDate 
 AND ac.DateTimeValue <= @finishDate
 AND COALESCE(pc.IsBusinessDay, ac.IsBusinessDay) = 0
```